# Convert wide data to long format for repeated measures/mixed models

Tags: r, tidyr

Currently I have data in this "wide" format:

```
|Participant|Banana|Apple|Orange|
|-|-|-|-|
|P1|0|0|0|
|P2|1|1|1|
|P3|0|0|0|
```

Ideally, I want to convert these data to long format for mixed models, i.e.,

```
|Participant|Item|Accuracy|
|-|-|-|
|P1|Banana|0|
|P1|Apple|0|
|P1|Orange|0|
|P2|Banana|1|
|P2|Apple|1|
|P2|Orange|1|
|P3|Banana|0|
|P3|Apple|0|
|P3|Orange|0|
```

(for some reason my tables are breaking, sorry folks.)

## Code to reproduce

```
dat <- data_frame(
  Participant = paste0("P", 1:3),
  Banana = sample(0:1, 3, TRUE),
  Apple = sample(0:1, 3, TRUE),
  Orange = sample(0:1, 3, TRUE),
)
```

Been combing through a few posts and there are bits and pieces of the answer around but I can't quite put it together re: extracting and splicing the participants and transposing their rows.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With `tidyr` could you do `pivot_longer(dat, cols = -Participant)`?

Comment: (fyi, you can still accept an answer even if marked as a dupe :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(wide, -Participant, names_to = "Item", values_to = "Accuracy")
# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   Participant Item   Accuracy
#   <chr>       <chr>     <int>
# 1 P1          Banana        0
# 2 P1          Apple         0
# 3 P1          Orange        0
# 4 P2          Banana        1
# 5 P2          Apple         1
# 6 P2          Orange        1
# 7 P3          Banana        0
# 8 P3          Apple         0
# 9 P3          Orange        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

dat %>%
  melt %>%
  rename(., Accuracy = value, Item = variable) %>%
  arrange(Participant)


  Participant   Item Accuracy
1          P1 Banana        0
2          P1  Apple        1
3          P1 Orange        0
4          P2 Banana        1
5          P2  Apple        0
6          P2 Orange        1
7          P3 Banana        1
8          P3  Apple        1
9          P3 Orange        1
```

Thanks to @r2evans

```
melt(dat, variable.name = "Accuracy", value.name = "Item")

  Participant Accuracy Item
1          P1   Banana    0
2          P2   Banana    1
3          P3   Banana    1
4          P1    Apple    1
5          P2    Apple    0
6          P3    Apple    1
7          P1   Orange    0
8          P2   Orange    1
9          P3   Orange    1
```

Comment: Or just `melt(dat, variable.name = "Accuracy", measure.name = "Item")` without the need for pipes or renaming.

Comment: @r2evans Wow. I didn't notice that. By the way, it seems that `value.name` works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did mean `value.name=`, thanks for catching that typo ... I was playing with other reshaping and didn't QA/check what I typed, sorry about that.

Comment: @r2evans Not a problem! I'm so grateful to remind `melt` function have those arguments. I usually tends to let them `variable` and `value`. Thanks again reminding me :D